# Golang - writing to ResponseWriter in a loop

Tags: loops, go

I have a simple function that is supposed to send multiple sets of data to the frontend.

```
func (m *Repository) Loop(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        jData, err := json.Marshal(fmt.Sprint("LOOP: ", i))
        if err != nil {
        }
        w.Write(jData)
    }

}
```

I am using `$.ajax` to handle it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/loopTest",
    data: null,
    success: function(resultData) {
      console.log(resultData);
    }
})
```

The issue is that instead of getting one response per second, I am getting all of them at once after the loop is finished.

I am stuck. All suggestions/links/tutorials/articles are appreciated.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks for the answers. Flushing + updating my `$.ajax success` callback solved the issue.

The code looks like this now:

go:

```
func (m *Repository) Loop(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(2  * time.Second)
        jData, err := json.Marshal(fmt.Sprint("LOOP: ", i))
        if err != nil {
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Write(jData)
        w.(http.Flusher).Flush()

    }

}
```

javascript

```
                function loopTest(){
                  var saveDataAll = $.ajax({
                              type: 'POST',
                              url: "/loopTest",
                              data: null,
                              xhrFields: {
                                onprogress: function(e){
                                  console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
                                }
                              }
                            })

                }
```

I had to also update other parts of the code. I was using chi router with alexedwards/scs session manager. Because of that (I think) I was unable to cast my response writer to Flusher. I changed my session manager to kataras/go-session which works fine now.

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution, but it's a good place to start!

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher

Comment: The $.ajax success callback is invoked when the request succeeds. The request succeeds after the complete response body is read from the server. If your goal is to read an event stream, then use the [event source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) API on the client and write the data in [event stream format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format) on the server.  The format is very simple.  Per previous comment, flush between events.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I had some issues with flushing. I'm using chi router with alexedwards/scs session manager and I couldn't use flush() method. I didn't know how to resolve that, so I changed my session manager to kataras/go-session. I added all the necessary headers, set the content-type to text/event-stream and changed the success  to onprogress. Now the data is send in real time. Thanks again!